# Why does the editor insert a final newline for JSON files, despite configuring it not to do so?

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, editorconfig

I have the following `.editorconfig`:

```
root = true

[package.json]
insert_final_newline = false
```

This is the VS Code configuration:

```
"files.insertFinalNewline": false,
```

- When selecting all content of `package.json` and choosing *Format Selection*, a final newline is removed when present.
- When choosing *Format Document*, a final newline is added when missing.
- When saving the file, a final newline is added when missing.

What could be causing the final newline to be added?

Answer (score 1):

The following extensions are known to interfere:

- esbenp.prettier-vscode: as per [#305](https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode/issues/305), inserting a final newline is not configurable and is always done.